# Which is a better refactoring tool for a beginner (something easy to learn & use)?

Tags: refactoring

Resharper, RefactorPro, etc?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using Resharper for some while and also CodeRush with Refactor later on.

I have stayed with CodeRush/Refactor. There is one major difference - the discoverability of the commands. Their learning videos are quite nice and show you a lot.

Most importantly Coderush has one key/shortcut for all refactorings which makes you much more likely to actually use them. There is side window that shows you what keys to press in order to use the templates as well. I have liked Resharper's searching for usage of a method, but CodeRush has a similar feature ignited by Shift + F12 and you can also simply press Tab on a variable, function etc. to jump to its next usage.

I also liked the interface of CodeRush/Refactor more.

One of the pro's for Resharper is the integrated testing tool so yuo can run test directly from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Resharper I've tried both Coderush and [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) from Whole Tomato Software.

In my opinion none of the above could measure up to [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) from Jetbrains which I decided to go for.  The others have many great features but Resharper is in a class of it's own. IMHO Coderush looks cooler, but I found Resharper more helpful.

In response to Tomas note about discoverability: I agree it's tough relearning all the shortcuts.  But to ease the transistion Resharper also has a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which will show all refactorings appropriate for the thing the cursor is placed on:

[image: Resharper context menu]

My recommendation is download a trial of all three, try one of them at a time for a while, and make your own choice.

Comment: I agree, both CodeRush and RefactorPro are visually impressive (most of which can be turned off BTW), but for navigating and refactoring Resharper is much better in my opinion of using both products.

Answer (score 0):

I think ReSharper is great.  I've been using it for 3 years now and I just love it more and more.